# Cannot build the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Installed the below chaincode in chaincode-docker-devmode network it works fine.

But when I tried to install the chaincode in the basic-network in the fabric-sample getting the following error.

Help me to solve this.

> asset.go:10:2: cannot find package >"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode                                                                                                                                                 >/shim" in any of:
>             /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from >$GOR                                                                                                                                                 >OOT)
>             /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim >>(from                                                                                                                                                  $GOPATH)
>       asset.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer" i                                                                                                                                                 n any of:
>               /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer (from $GOROOT)
>               /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer (from $GOPATH)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    sc "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
    )

// Define the Smart Contract structure

type SmartContract struct {
}

//Define assets structure

type Asset struct {
    asset_id string `json:"asset_id"`
    asset_name string `json:"asset_name"`
    owner_aadhar int `json:"owner_aadhar"`
    owner_name string `json:"owner_name"`
    debt bool `json:"debt"`
    lamount int `json:"lamount"`
    objection string `json:"objection"`
    }


func (s *SmartContract) Init(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// The calling application program has also specified the particular smart contract function to be called, with arguments

func (s *SmartContract) Invoke(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {

    function, args := APIstub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

    if function == "initLedger"{
        return s.initLedger(APIstub)
    }

    if function == "transfer_asset"{
        return s.transfer_asset(APIstub,args)
    }

    if function == "create_asset"{
        return  s.create_asset(APIstub,args)
    }

    if function == "view_asset" {
        return s.view_asset(APIstub,args)
    }


    return shim.Error("Invalid Smart Contract function name.")
}

//stores some sample assets

func (s *SmartContract) initLedger(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
    assets := []Asset{
        Asset{asset_id:"A101", asset_name:"1bhk", owner_aadhar:101, owner_name:"praveen", debt:false, lamount:0, objection:"nill"},
        Asset{asset_id:"A102", asset_name:"factory",owner_aadhar:102, owner_name:"arun", debt:false, lamount:0, objection:"nill"},
        Asset{asset_id:"A103", asset_name:"abt school", owner_aadhar:103, owner_name:"kevin", debt:true, lamount:100000, objection:"nill"},
        Asset{asset_id:"A104", asset_name:"2bhk", owner_aadhar:104, owner_name:"baaruni",debt:false, lamount:0, objection:"1case"},
    }

    i := 0

    for i< len(assets)  {
        assetAsBytes, _ :=json.Marshal(assets[i])
        APIstub.PutState(assets[i].asset_id, assetAsBytes)
        i++
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (s *SmartContract) create_asset(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args[] string) sc.Response  {
    if len(args)!=7 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments expected 7")
    }
    taadhar, _ :=strconv.Atoi(args[2])
    tdept, _ := strconv.ParseBool(args[4])
    tlamount, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[5])
    var asset = Asset{asset_id:args[0], asset_name:args[1], owner_aadhar:taadhar, owner_name:args[3], debt:tdept, lamount:tlamount, objection:args[6]}
    assetAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(asset)
    APIstub.PutState(asset.asset_id,assetAsBytes)
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (s *SmartContract) transfer_asset(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args[] string) sc.Response{

    if len(args) !=3 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments expected 3")
    }

    assetAsBytes, _ :=APIstub.GetState(args[0])
    asset := Asset{}

    json.Unmarshal(assetAsBytes, &asset)

    if (asset.objection!="nill")||(asset.debt!=false){
        return shim.Error("Asset cannot be transfer as it has some issues")
    }
    asset.owner_aadhar, _ = strconv.Atoi(args[1])

    assetAsBytes, _ =json.Marshal(asset)
    APIstub.PutState(args[0],assetAsBytes)

    return shim.Success(nil)

}

func (s *SmartContract) view_asset(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args[] string) sc.Response  {
    if len(args) !=1{
        return shim.Error("Invalid number of arguments expected 1")
    }

    assetAsBytes, _ :=APIstub.GetState(args[0])
    asset := Asset{}

    json.Unmarshal(assetAsBytes, &asset)
    return shim.Success(assetAsBytes)
}
```

Comment: Which commands are you using?

Comment: go build - to build the chaincode and go get -to pull the package

Comment: So you are just trying to build the chaincode locally on your machine?  Did you run "go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" and "go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer" ?

Comment: No i want to install it in fabcar network. but as the build fails I cannot proceed further

Comment: actually I can install this chaincode in chaincode-docker-devmode network. but it showing the above error in fabcar network

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by install?

Comment: which means deploying the chaincode in the channel

Comment: Are you doing "peer chaincode install" or "peer chaincode instantiate" ?

Comment: yes I do but i cannot execut "peer chaincode install " as there is a error in "go build"

Comment: OK .... you need to have the shim and proto packages in your GOPATH prior to running the install command.  Try running the two go get commands from my comment above and then do the install

Comment: yes i did but cannot solve the issue

Comment: on running "go get " command getting "package plugin: unrecognized import path "plugin" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package context: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does not begin with hostname)"
g >

Comment: You need use Go 1.9.x for Fabric v1.1

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get following go libraries to compile chaincode locally.

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
```

These libraries will be installed under GOPATH, make sure it is set.

In case if you get any(specific to context and plugin) errors for "go get" command , then follow the procedure mentioned below to resolve.

Upgrade to latest version of GO.

```
sudo apt-get purge golang*

sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/go-1.6/ /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/ /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/ /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/race

curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.11.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.11.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

mkdir -p ~/go; echo "export GOPATH=$HOME/go" >> ~/.bashrc

echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

Then

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer
```

Answer (score 0):

there are new links to import shim and peer. Below worked fine.

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer
```

Refer this link -
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/chaincode4ade.html